# Can I get multiple intents for a single user query with their confidence scores?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es

I need to answer questions for multiple intent for user query. But dialogflow is only returning one intent at a time which is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible** with DialogFlow.
DialogFlow is designed in such a way that it returns the best matching intent only.
You should try [LUIS](https://www.luis.ai/) or [RASA](https://rasa.com/).